# What is the alternative to using **label** in solidity inline assembly code?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, assembly

What is the alternative to using `label` in Solidity inline assembly code? Label is deprecated in new version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.6/assembly.html#labels), support for labels has been removed in version 0.5.0 of Solidity. Please use functions, loops, if or switch statements instead.